# Best practice to convert date string from json to UI

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

So we have a json response that looks like this:

```
  {
    data: {
      nestedData: {
        someMoreNestedData: {
          someArray: [
            {
              someWhereThereIsADate: '2018-10-26'
            }
          ]
        },
        wholeBunchOfOtherData: {...}
      }
    }
  }
```

Right now the date format is 'yyyy-MM-dd', but it could change to something else like 'yyyyMMdd' or 'MM/dd/yyyy', etc.

The UI wants to display in 'MM/dd/yyyy' right now, but it could change to other format in the future.

So let's create a function like this (in typescript):

```
  function dateStringFormat(dateString: string, inFormat: string, outFormat: string): string {
    if (!dateString || inFormat === outFormat) {
      return dateString;
    }
    // use luxon DateTime to convert
    return DateTime.fromString(dateString, inFormat).toFormat(outFormat);
  }
```

The trouble is that dateString and inFormat are tightly coupled.

What about we split this into two functions, one for parsing the dateString into JavaScript Date.  And the second function for formatting the JavaScript Date.  But we will be not able to short circuit the conversion when inFormat and outFormat are the same.

The other idea is to convert the JSON response into a data object where the date strings are converted into Dates.  But that sounds heavy.

I wonder if anyone has gone through this and come up with some best practices.

Comment: moment is good for dates data type manipulation https://momentjs.com/

Comment: The only way to keep this flexible is to use a parser that recognizes each possible format. MomentJS is a great solution. Additionally, the data format can be attached to each structure so clients don't have to guess.

Comment: Guys, I am already using luxon, which is like moment, for date formats.  The question is not regarding on formatting work, but the best practices to streamline a backend date in json to a UI date in any format

Answer (score 0):

The question is tagged for Angular, but it looks like you are using raw JS.   If it is in Angular, why not use the Date pipe?

https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

```
{{ dateObj | date }}               // output is 'Jun 15, 2015'
{{ dateObj | date:'medium' }}      // output is 'Jun 15, 2015, 9:43:11 PM'
{{ dateObj | date:'shortTime' }}   // output is '9:43 PM'
{{ dateObj | date:'mmss' }}        // output is '43:11'
```

Comment: According to the doc, dateObj can only be in milliseconds since UTC epoch or ISO string, right?

Comment: You can create your own pipe that uses the DatePipe internally. Pipe are provided like services, so you can inject the Angular DatePipe in the constructor or your custom date pipe. You'll just need to handle the conversion in the pipe's transform method and and use the Angular DatePipe transform method to return the result.